# Regular Expression Reverse Matching - Url with some special characters not in it

Tags: regex, .htaccess, preg-match

So I have been trying for the past 3 hours to find a solution to this problem.Finally posting this on StackOverflow as I cannot find any solution. The problem is that I have URLs of the form

```
/myurlbase/firstname-lastname-nameId
```

firstname is a string
lastname is a string and this is optional(so url can be /myurlbase/firstname-nameId) 
nameID is a number

I want the regular expression to **match** only those urls **where the firstname and lastname do not have any special characters** in them.However the names **can have foreign accented characters.(UTF-8 encoded)**

I am using it as a .htaccess rule so the expression has to match. Please don't reply with an answer that says match the other way round and put a not in the front.

Comment: What is a "special character"? You want only letters/numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^myurlbase/([a-z]+)-(?:([a-z]+)-)?([0-9]+)/?$ /target?fn=$1&ln=$2&id=$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I don't see how this will work. This way the first name will be matched with only a-z whereas I need to match special characters as well. Any suggestions?(Thanks for answering though)

Comment: Did you not you write this in question: **where the firstname and lastname do not have any special characters**?

Comment: You need to provide examples of all the different cases of URIs that you want to handle.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to add that accented characters should pass the test.Examples of this would be:- /pünter-king-1245 should pass but /pun$er-king-1245 should not pass. I have a list of special characters like $ that should not pass other than that all characters in the utf-8 charset should pass.

Comment: If you have a list of characters that should not pass then provide that list by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=\b\/(\w+)-(\w+)\b-.*?$)

RewriteRule ^myurlbase/(?=\b\/(\w+)-(\w+)\b-.*?$) /page.php?fn=$1&ln=$2 [L,NC]


Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=\b\/(\w+)-(\w+)\b-.*?$)»
   Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
   Match the character “/” literally «\/»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w+)»
      Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the character “-” literally «-»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\w+)»
      Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
   Match the character “-” literally «-»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!

Comment: Me again! I don't have anything against you personally, I just post that comment on almost every answer I see that can be improved by an explanation.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I was kidding with you my friend It's always a pleasure to read you, honestly ;)

Comment: Hey I am really sorry but I forgot to add that I need to pass foreign accented characters. Can you please tell me what to do ?

Comment: Hey I am really sorry I forgot to add that I need to pass foreign accented characters. Can you please help me with that ?